# MACRO Function doesn't return an objective C object

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macros

I'm defining a `MACRO` function to return me an `NSDictionary` object. Here is the code that I tried

```
#define GetDictionary(name,description,imageName) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[name,description,imageName] forKeys:@[ATTRIBUTE_TITLE,ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION,ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_NAME]]

#define GetDictionary(name,description,imageName) @{ATTRIBUTE_TITLE:name,ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION:description,ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_NAME:imageName}
```

But evety time I try to call this method to get a dictionary object, the compiler gives an error "**collection element of type `void *` is not an objective c object**". Immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code that calls these macros and show the definition for the other constants used in the macro.

Comment: Macros are not functions.  They are mechanisms for transforming code at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if all possible, avoid these kinds of macros. They tend to cause exactly these kinds of headaches. I assume you have further macros for `ATTRIBUTE_TITLE`, etc. I highly recommend using simple functions rather than macros. You'll get much easier-to-understand code. There is seldom a reason to use macros this way.

My first suspicion is that `ATTRIBUTE_TITLE` (or one of the related macros) is not a proper object. Most likely you've done something like:

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_TITLE "foo"
```

rather than

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_TITLE @"foo"
```

Though the `void*` complaint is interesting… Anyway, switching this to a function, and changing `ATTRIBUTE_*` to constants rather than macros, will likely make the error obvious.

Comment: Calling the macro with a NULL argument: `GetDictionary(@"name", @"desc", NULL)` or defining one of the `ATTRIBUTE_*` macros as NULL would cause exactly the error message given in the question.

Comment: Thanks; yes `NULL` does sound more likely than a cstring (since `NULL` is a `void*`).